# JavaScript API that converts cron expressions into human readable strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, cron, quartz-scheduler

I used below Javascript API to create Quartz compatible UI to provide cron expression to server side quartz sevices.

https://github.com/felixruponen/jquery-cron

Do we have any API , which we can use to convert cron expressions into human readable strings in Java Script.

Thanks

Comment: I searched a lot for javascript API to convert cron expressions into human readable format.  I did not found any quartz format compatible. Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recently ported the Quartz compatible [cron-expression-descriptor](https://github.com/bradyholt/cron-expression-descriptor) from C# to JavaScript and named it [cRonstrue](https://github.com/bradyholt/cronstrue).  This JavaScript library is able to convert a Quartz cron expression into a human readable string like this:

```
cronstrue.toString("0 23 ? * MON-FRI");
> "At 11:00 PM, Monday through Friday"
```

Comment: do you have any idea of loading cRonstrue module with require JS ?

Comment: @Dinesh It's distributed as a UMD module so you can just require it in RequireJS like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bradyholt/pquj207n/1/

Comment: @Brady I am trying to use in angular 2. Am getting an error saying `TypeError: cronstrue_1.cronstrue is not a function`. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I hope this can help others...
import cronstrue from 'cronstrue/i18n';
this.cronText = cronstrue.toString("0 5 10 12 *", { locale: 'pt_BR' });

Comment: @BradyHolt What about going from a human readable expression to a cron expression? Basically, the exact reverse operation as in your example.

Comment: @EgeErsoz - This library does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

[cronstrue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cronstrue)  - сurrently supported library