# Package to translate a cron to a "simpler" human readable format?

Tags: javascript, npm, cron, package, scheduling

I've been looking all over the internet for an NPM package that could achieve this, but I haven't been able to find one.

What I'm looking for is quite simple on the surface. A cron library that can translate a monthly cron job to human-readable text, while keeping it simple. So for example: if I put in `0 0 14 * *`, I want it to translate to "*Monthly*". Instead, this translates to "*At 00:00 on day-of-month 14.*" which is an awkward string to display to users.

More examples would be:

- `0 8 * * *` should translate to "*Daily*"
- `0 0 10 * *` should also translate to "*Monthly*"

I want to stay away from making my own proprietary library if possible. Does anyone know if there is any JS package out there that meets my requirements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263810/javascript-api-that-converts-cron-expressions-into-human-readable-strings

Comment: @0stone0 I've seen cronstrue, but it returns the long variant of the English string. I'm looking for a shorter version as described above

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cronstrue

cRonstrue is a JavaScript library that parses a cron expression and outputs a human readable description of the cron schedule.

```
cronstrue.toString("* * * * *");
> "Every minute"

cronstrue.toString("0 23 ? * MON-FRI");
> "At 11:00 PM, Monday through Friday"

cronstrue.toString("0 23 * * *", { verbose: true });
> "At 11:00 PM, every day"

cronstrue.toString("23 12 * * SUN#2");
> "At 12:23 PM, on the second Sunday of the month"

cronstrue.toString("23 14 * * SUN#2", { use24HourTimeFormat: true });
> "At 14:23, on the second Sunday of the month"

cronstrue.toString("* * * ? * 2-6/2", { dayOfWeekStartIndexZero: false });
> "Every second, every 2 days of the week, Monday through Friday"

cronstrue.toString("* * * 6-8 *", { monthStartIndexZero: true });
> "Every minute, July through September"
```

Comment: That's an awesome package – thanks! I've used to develop this utility https://ray.run/tools/cron-parser

Comment: @LucGagan Impressive